# iOS VPN auto disconnected after sometime

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, nevpnmanager

I'm working on a VPN application, VPN working fine but after 15-20 minutes, its automatically disconnected.
Here is configuration I'm using

```
        let vpnProtocol = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
        vpnProtocol.username = CredentialsManager.shared.accessToken
        vpnProtocol.localIdentifier = CredentialsManager.shared.accessToken

        print("VPN Connecting to \(self.region.name ?? "Error! Must be a valid region name!")")

        if let region = self.region {
          f
            vpnProtocol.serverAddress = region.serverAddress
            vpnProtocol.remoteIdentifier = region.serverAddress
        }

        let encodedIdentifier = "Secret Password".data(using: .utf8)!
        let item = [kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                    kSecAttrGeneric: encodedIdentifier,
                    kSecAttrAccount: encodedIdentifier,
                    kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitOne,
                    kSecReturnPersistentRef: kCFBooleanTrue as Any,
                    kSecAttrService: "XYZ"] as [CFString : Any]

        var passwordReference: CFTypeRef?
        SecItemCopyMatching(item as CFDictionary, &passwordReference)

        vpnProtocol.passwordReference = passwordReference as? Data
        vpnProtocol.authenticationMethod = .none
        vpnProtocol.useExtendedAuthentication = true

        vpnProtocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm =
            .algorithmAES256GCM
        vpnProtocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA384
        vpnProtocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group14

        vpnProtocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256GCM
        vpnProtocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = .SHA384
        vpnProtocol.childSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = .group14

        vpnProtocol.disconnectOnSleep = false

        self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = vpnProtocol
        let connectRule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
        connectRule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any

        self.vpnManager.onDemandRules = [connectRule]
        self.vpnManager.isOnDemandEnabled = self.connectOnDemand
        self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "XYZ VPN"
        self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true
```

Please help me out, how to identify problem that causing auto disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured ["connect on demand"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/personal_vpn/vpn_on_demand_rules?language=objc), so it will connect back automatically when you will access resource next time. That is how VPN on iOS works, it will always close connection on idle.

Comment: Already setup Connect on Demand , still not able to resolve this issue. If you have  configuration, that is working, please share I'll be thankful.

Comment: That is what I'm talking about: it is impossible to "resolve issue" that way you think: your on demand configuration is correct and that is all you can get from iOS, it is not possible to keep connection opened in background

Answer (score -1):

change your VPN protocol with this: NEVPNProtocolIPSec
maybe it will help you.

Comment: I don't this is a good Idea, Previously I use NEVPNProtocolIPSec and faced lots of issues and then I decided to use NEVPNProtocolIKEv2, and all other issue resolved but I'm still facing this issue.

Comment: hm I have no idea why your problem occurs unfortunately but just wondering because I'm using IKEV2 what kind of problems you have been faced before

Comment: if you are using IKEv2, let me know, you faced that auto disconnect issue ?

Comment: not now .. actually I have never connect VPN in  more than 5 minutes .

Comment: Same her but user complaining about disconnect issue, need to resolve.